# How to insert current_timestamp using Spring JDBCNamedParameterTemplate in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, spring-jdbc

I am using a prepared statement using Spring JDBCNamedParameterTemplate in MS SQL Server

```
String sqlUpsateEntity = "update mytable \n" + "set name = :myname, Current_Date = current_timestamp from mytable where mytable_id = :id";
```

"Current_Date = current_timestamp " gives error

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'Current_Date'."
```

How can I insert the current timestamp?

**Update**

@Martin Cairney pointed out the cause may be another issue and he is right.
When I added the 'Current_Date = current_timestamp' in the actual code, I had
forgotten to put a ',' after the previous clause. So current_timestamp works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax looks to be OK - I am not convinced that the use of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is your issue, but possible ways to check this include using the other system date and time options:
    SYSDATETIME()
    GETDATE()

I'd suggest trying with each of those to see if it does the same.

Another option, without seeing your table schema and parameter values is that there is a mis-match between those.  Check that you are passing the appropriate data type for `:myname` and also that `Current_Date` is a `DATETIME` data type and also that the value passed for `:id` matches the data type of column `mytable_id`.

Comment: you are right. see my update to the question. thanks!